# What is the benefit of passing a delegate to the constructor instead of just having the client code create and pass the ParserSettings?

Tags: c#, configuration

When answering a [question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733865/c-sharp-commandline-parser-use-constructor-that-accepts-actionparsersettings), the library appeared to have a weird way to specify configuration, through an `Action` passed to the constructor:

```
public Parser(Action<ParserSettings> configuration)
{
    if (configuration == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("configuration");
    this.settings = new ParserSettings();
    configuration(this.settings);
    this.settings.Consumed = true;
}

internal Parser(ParserSettings settings)
{
    this.settings = settings;
    this.settings.Consumed = true;
}
```

So to specify the settings you provide a `Action<ParserSettings>` that modifies the settings:

```
var parser = new Parser( s => { s.CaseSensitive = false; } );
```

I don't understand what this pattern accomplishes. What is the benefit of passing a delegate to the constructor instead of just having the client code create and pass the `ParserSettings` to the constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing a delegate allows the caller instantiating the object to inject *custom initialization behavior.*  Note the `configuration(this.settings)` call in the constructor code, which executes the behavior provided by the constructor delegate.

I can think of a number of reasons why this might be handy.  One hypothetical example might be that of providing platform independence.  This is a command line parser; if the parser can be called on Windows or Unix systems, passing a first-class function to the constructor allows the initialization to detect the platform, and adjust the parser settings based on which platform it is running on.

**Further Reading**
[Open-Closed Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)
[Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)

Comment: But can't you do that before you create the parser anyway? `ParserSettings GetConfiguration( ... ){ ... } var parser = new Parser( GetConfiguration( ... ) );` It just seems like an extra layer of indirection.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide a better example.  Basically, by accepting a delegate, you allow the caller to *execute their own code* during the instantiation process.

Comment: That makes sense, maybe it is just this example that is throwing me. As it sits now all it does is create new settings and pass it to the delegate to initialize it, but I guess it could do something useful before calling the delegate, like set case insensitivity if on Windows... Which now as I re-read your answer is exactly what you said. I was thinking you were saying the delegate could determine the platform ..

Comment: Right, exactly.  Accepting a delegate allows the caller to pass *data and behavior,* not just data.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the constructor creates a new `ParserSettings` objects and passes it unmodified to the supplied delegate. This does seem overly convoluted - why not just have the client create the `ParserSettings` object and pass it as a regular argument to the constructor?

But consider if library developers wanted to change how the initial settings are created, e.g load them from a configuration file or initialize using some conditional logic. The use of a delegate hides this complexity for user of the API, and allows the logic to change without affecting the clients.

You could still avoid the use of a delegate by fetching the settings in a seperate method call, e.g.:

```
ParserSettings s = Parser.GetDefaultSettings(); 
s.CaseSensitive = false;
var parser = new Parser(s);
```

But this have several drawbacks compared to the delegate. The API surface is bigger as you need to expose how to load the default configuration, something which can be completely encapsulated in the delegate-version. It needlessly introduces the the risk of passing an incorrect settings-object (e.g. is it allowed to re-use the same settings for multiple parser?). The API is less discoverable: While it is obvious you need to call `new Parser` to initialize a parser, it is not immediately obvious how to get the requred settings object. Especially if you dont need to modify the settings, it seems overly convoluted.

In short, providing a delegate which allows the client to inspect and modify the settings give you both flexibility and simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having to provide a full configuration, the caller has the option of modifying a given configuration. He might decide to just tweak the existing configuration.

```
var parser = new Parser( s => { 
    s.IgnoreUnknownArguments = s.IgnoreUnknownArguments || s.CaseSensitive;
} );
```

The delegate could be stored by the Parser and be called again whenever changes are made to the configuration.

Comment: I don't see how the delegate buys you much there.  If the constructor accepted a `ParserSettings` object instead of a delegate, you could still do this quite easily.

Comment: Sure, if the default configuration is always the same. But the parser could decide to use different standard configurations depending on the file type being processed or even let preprocessor macros modify it. This would give the delegate the opportunity to just check a given configuration and make changes where appropriate instead of just providing a constant set of configuration settings.

Comment: The existing configuration would have to already exist outside of the parser (remember, this is a constructor call).

Comment: The constructor could execute some logic modifying the configuration before calling the delegate. And in future versions of the parser the delegate could be called later in the parsing process. This makes the code fit for the future. (This is what the Open-Closed Principle is all about.)

Answer (score 0):

Relay command pattern used extensively in WPF is good example. Viewmodel provides implementation of `ICommand` via `RealyCommand`. So view model injects action to be executed whenever command is triggered from UI.

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand    
{    
    private Action<object> execute;    
    private Func<object, bool> canExecute;    

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged    
    {    
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }    
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }    
    }    

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)    
    {    
        this.execute = execute;    
        this.canExecute = canExecute;    
    }    

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)    
    {    
        return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute(parameter);    
    }    

    public void Execute(object parameter)    
    {    
        this.execute(parameter);    
    }    
}
```

Your `ViewModel` can expose property (say Save) of type `ICommand` which is binded to button command property. Like :

```
public ICommand Save{
get {return new RelayCommand(o => { /* do something 1 */ }, o => true); }
```